# Hibernate OneToOne Relationship: Unable to delete the child table

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, one-to-one

Let's say we are living in a world a person could have only one vehicle(Forgive me for my lame example)

Let's say I have this `UserDetails` Class

```
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public Vehicle getVehicle() {
        return  vehicle;
    }

    public void setVehicle(Vehicle  vehicle) {
        this.vehicle =  vehicle;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And this is My `Vehicle` class

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long vechile_id;
    private String vehicleName;
    public long getVechile_id() {
        return vechile_id;
    }
    public void setVechile_id(long vechile_id) {
        this.vechile_id = vechile_id;
    }

    public String getVehicleName() {
        return vehicleName;
    }
    public void setVehicleName(String vehicleName) {
        this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
    }   
}
```

Upon Saving it to the database it works fine, but when I went to delete the Table for vehicle this error showed up on my workbench

**NOTE** That there are only one entries on both `UserDetails` and `Vehicle` Table.

```
ERROR 1217: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

SQL Statement:

drop table `hibernate`.`vehicle`
```

How come am I not allowed to drop the table? Should I delete The UserDetails table first?

Comment: how are you deleting the table? What DB are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL right clicking then "Drop Table"

Comment: The error seems pretty clear; you're not allowed to drop the table because there is still a foreign key constraint; in other words a record in another table still has a foreign key to a record in the table you're trying to drop. That's basic database stuff, nothing related to Hibernate. Are you really sure you want to drop the table and not delete records from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd delete the Vehicle table, that would make the UserDetails table loose it's referential integrity because the vehicle column's foreign keys would point to nowhere. Drop the fk constraint or the vehicle column from UserDetails then you can delete the table you want.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that referential Integrity, so looks like I would have to loose or remove its FK constraint then drop the Vehicle table? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. Dropping the fk column is the better I think, unless you wish to change the column to represent vehicles in an other way. (Then drop fk + alter column is good)